# Failed to reflect on template html by shared service

Tags: angular

I am trying to achieve simply to reflect API data on a template.  I have a component of listing. User listing, which has a details link in it. By clicking that, one calls another component. I have a menu section which should change by this time. Menus are coming from my node server. So I have to change menu when I click on the details link of the user list and go to the details component. All 3 components are unrelated I suppose. I am posting the files below

menu service is which I used as a shared service and wrote a emitchange function to make the menu change and by using mainMenuService.menuChangeEmitted$.subscribe trying to get that from both the component. clientlist.component.html is that where I call the appconfig.component.ts. But the menu is not getting updated.

main-menu.service.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MainMenuService {

  private menuSource = new BehaviorSubject<any>([]);
  currentMenu = this.menuSource.asObservable();
  mainMenuItems: MainMenuItem[];
  // Observable string sources
  private emitChangeSource = new Subject();

  // Observable string streams
  menuChangeEmitted$ = this.emitChangeSource.asObservable();

  private apiUrl;
  constructor(private http: Http, private errorService: ErrorService, private router: Router) {
    this.apiUrl = environment.apiUrl;
  }

  changeMenu(menu: any){
    //console.log(menu);
    this.menuSource.next(menu);
  }

  // Service message commands
  emitChange(change: MainMenuItem[]) {
    this.emitChangeSource.next(change);
  }
```

main-menu.component.ts

```
export class MainMenuComponent {
  mainMenuItems: MainMenuItem[];

  constructor(private mainMenuService: MainMenuService) {
    mainMenuService.menuChangeEmitted$.subscribe(
      menu => {
        console.log(menu)
        this.mainMenuItems = <MainMenuItem[]>menu;
        //localStorage.setItem('roles', JSON.stringify(menu.roles));
      }
    );
  }

  getMainMenuItems(): void {
    this.mainMenuService.getMainMenuItems()
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                //console.log(data);
                //this.mainMenuItems = data.menus;
                this.mainMenuService.emitChange(data.menus);

                localStorage.setItem('roles', JSON.stringify(data.roles));
                //console.log(JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('roles')));
            },
            error => {
              console.log(error);
    });
    //this.mainMenuService.getMainMenuItems().then(mainMenuItems => this.mainMenuItems = mainMenuItems);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getMainMenuItems();



  }


}
```

appconfig.component.ts

```
  export class AppconfigComponent {
config(id){
    if(localStorage.getItem('user_type') == 'admin' || localStorage.getItem('user_type') == 'subadmin'){
      localStorage.setItem('clientAppId', this.appid);
      localStorage.setItem('user_type', 'client');
      this.mainMenuService.getMainMenuItems()
          .subscribe(
              data => {
                  this.mainMenuService.emitChange(data.menus);
                  localStorage.setItem('roles', JSON.stringify(data.roles));
              },
              error => {
                console.log(error);
      });
    }
}
}
```

menu html

```
<nav class="main-menu">
  <ul>
    <li
      class="menu-item"
      *ngFor="let item of mainMenuItems"
      [ngClass]="{
        'has-sub': item.sub,
        'active': item.active,
        'menu-item-group': item.groupTitle
      }"
      class="{{item.customClass}}"
      routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
    >
      <!-- Group title -->
      <span class="group-title" *ngIf="item.groupTitle">{{ item.title }}</span>

      <!-- Simple item -->
      <a href="#" routerLink="{{ item.routing }}" class="item-link" *ngIf="!item.groupTitle && !item.sub">
        <span class="text">{{ item.title }}</span>
        <span class="item-badge" *ngIf="item.budge" [ngStyle]="{'background': item.budgeColor}">{{ item.budge }}</span>
        <span class="icon"></span>
        <!-- <span class="icon1">
            <img src="assets/img/logo-1.png" alt="">
        </span> -->

      </a>

      <!-- Item with sub -->
      <a href="#" class="item-link" *ngIf="!item.groupTitle && item.sub" (click)="toggle($event, item, this)">
        <span class="text">{{ item.title }}</span>
        <span class="item-badge" *ngIf="item.budge" [ngStyle]="{'background': item.budgeColor}">{{ item.budge }}</span>
        <i class="caret fa fa-angle-right" *ngIf="item.sub"></i>
        <span class="icon" *ngIf="item.icon" [ngClass]="item.icon"></span>
      </a>

      <!-- Menu sub -->
      <ul class="sub" *ngIf="!item.groupTitle && item.sub">
        <li
          class="menu-item"
          *ngFor="let itemSub of item.sub"
          routerLinkActive="active" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact:true}"
        >
          <a href="#" routerLink="{{ itemSub.routing }}" class="item-link">{{ itemSub.title }}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a service multiple times, then you'll get multiple instances of that service. If you update the state of one instance, the other instance won't change.

Remove the service provider in the component and only keep it in the module.

Providing is about how many instances are created, how they are created, and to what part of the application the instances will be available to.

Injecting is requesting an instance from  a provider. That is done by adding a constructor parameter to a class that is created by DI (component, directive, service, ...)

Comment: You mean I remove the services from component and declare that in app module provider? But then how to call them in components?

Comment: I mean to remove it from `providers: [...]` in `@Component()` is all

Comment: okay I removed them from providers of components and the service is already added in ngmodule. this.mainMenuService.emitChange(data.menus); this is done in appconfig.componetn.ts I get the updated data in console but it's not reflecting the menu html :(

Comment: Your question contains way too much code. It should be reduced to contain only what is necessary to reproduce the issue by itself, not in the context of a full application. It's too complicated to try to understand this amount of code.

Comment: reduced. I am using emitChange when details link is clicked and appconfig component is called. Hoping the emitchange in the appconfig will effec the menu html.

Comment: Now the "menu HTML" you mentioned in the previous comment is missing ;-)

Comment: added :). Can I get the APi change value by emitChange from a component class reflected to another component html?

Comment: Sure, you can inject the service to any component and subscribe to changes.

Comment: Again, most of the HTML you added is just noise. I can't imagine the problem needs several `*ngFor` or `ngClass`, ... to be discussed.